# Java - cannot convert double to integer while dividing doubles

Tags: java, integer, double, calculation

Pretty new to this, trying to set up a project where **jonkos** is the result of **gramassie** divided by **jonkowaarde**.

I keep getting the error: "Cannot convert from double to int"

Code:

```
package test;
    import java.util.Scanner; 
    import java.lang.Math.*;
public class jonkocalculator {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //kijken hoeveel jonkos je kunt draaien uit hoeveelheid assie
        Scanner jonkoscanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        double  jonkowaarde, gramassie;

        jonkowaarde = 0.3;

        System.out.println("Hoeveel gram assie heb je g?");
        gramassie = jonkoscanner.nextDouble();

        int jonkos = (int)gramassie/jonkowaarde; //this is where the error occurs

        System.out.println("Met "+gramassie+" gram kun je "+jonkos+" jonkos draaien g");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(int)gramassie/jonkowaarde
```

converts `gramassie` to an int, and divides it by a double. So the result of the division is a double, that you try to assign to an int variable (hence the error).

You want the result of the division to be a int, not `gramassie`. So it should be

```
(int) (gramassie / jonkowaarde)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Was stuck with this for hours after our java class ended and the teacher walked away ;P

Comment: When you start, especially when you're stuck with such a problem, it's always better to do one thing per line. So you'd better write the code using `double divisionResult = gramassie/jonkowaarde; int resultAsInt = (int) divisionResult;`

Answer (score 1):

The operator **cast** (`(type)value`) takes precedence over **divide**(`/`). So, your code means this:

```
int jonkos = ((int)gramassie)/jonkowaarde;
```

First `grassamie` is converted to `int`, then it's divided by `jonkowaarde` - which is still `double`, so it produces a `double`! To fix this, add parentheses:

```
int jonkos = (int)(gramassie/jonkowaarde);
```